# dataTables jquery make any part of the row clickable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to click on any part of row and get the response. Currently I am only able to click on row 3 to get the data.
here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/byhs/

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your selector using `td:eq(2)` to `td`.

Comment: please share code.. I want to make each row click-able and want to edit data in a popup... help me..